# Sending an alert to a slack channel by clicking a specific hyperlink in a page. How do I make it work?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to send an alert to my Slack channel every time a user clicks on a specific hyperlink and in this case, it's the "link" element within the page. What I have now is, every time a user clicks on any part of the page, I receive that alert. How do I resolve this?

Part of the code:

```
let link = document.createElement("a"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! a research on Google seems to give some results. Have you already tried something ?

Comment: Hi Gobes, thanks for the comment. Yes I did try researching but with my requirements it seems nothing works. I know that there is and I’m hoping someone can direct me to that solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does addEventListener is sending logs 6 times whenever I click a hyperlink in a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76334440/why-does-addeventlistener-is-sending-logs-6-times-whenever-i-click-a-hyperlink-i)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [AJAX Calls](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) for this.
You can use [this](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks) for how to send messages to slack.

I hope this helps.

Comment: HI GTD, thanks for the comment. I will check on the AJAX Calls and see if this works for me. With regards to sending the alert to a slack channel, this one works, however, like i mentioned, every time the user clicks in any part of the page, it calls the log which sends to my webhook url. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if ajax calls will apply to my requirement but thanks for the suggestion. Anyone can fix or suggest the code i’m missing? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned **specific hyperlink**, wouldn't adding a simple onclick function work in your case?

```js
function sendalert(link) {
  //do your ajax here
  alert(`link sent for ${link}`)
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="sendalert('link 1')">send</a>
```

Comment: Hi @someone special, thank you for the suggestion but in my case this code doesn't work. I did find the answer I need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76334440/why-does-addeventlistener-is-sending-logs-6-times-whenever-i-click-a-hyperlink-i?noredirect=1#comment134608115_76334440