# Why does addEventListener is sending logs 6 times whenever I click a hyperlink in a page?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

my addEventListener is sending logs 6 times whenever I click a hyperlink in a page. I have been checking what causing it and I couldn't figure out why. I know there are similar questions like this in this forum but I don't know why it's sending 6 logs to my webhook url. Appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why are you adding the event listener to `link` instead of `linkText`? You're adding 6 event listeners to `link`.

Comment: If you're adding event listeners in a loop then it seems reasonable that multiple event listeners would be added.  It's not really clear to me what the intent is here.

Comment: I suspect you want to move the creation of `link` into the loop, so there are 6 different links, not just one link.

Comment: Is this code part of another loop? You probably don't need the nested `forEach()`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, thank you for the response. To answer your question, if I do this, nothing happens if i click a hyperlink. This will not send a log to my webhook url. document.querySelectorAll('[class^="awsui_tabs-content"]').forEach(link => {linkText.addEventListener("click", (e) => {log('A link was clicked');
                });
                });

Comment: What element does that selector match? You need to use a selector that matches the hyperlinks.

Comment: That's why we need a MRE -- we need to see your HTML, and understand where you're trying to add the hyperlink in it.

Comment: Somewhat related, you don't need to use an `<a>` element just to have something to click on. Just about any visible element supports the `click` event. Hyperlinks are for navigation and shouldn't be used solely as a "hook" for a click event.

Comment: Hi @Barmar thanks a lot, this resolves the issue that Sam Spade shared. Appreciate you checking on the code. let eventListenerFunction = (e) => {log('A link was clicked'); }
                document.querySelectorAll('[class^="awsui_tabs-content"]').forEach(linkText => {
                link.addEventListener("click", eventListenerFunction );
});

Answer (score 1):

Because you are adding 6 event listeners to the `onClick` of the link.

I can think of two ways to solve this depending on what you are trying to do. Because I'm not sure, I'll just give you both, but I'd advise you clarify your question.

PS: I have also renamed one of your variables to reduce confusion because you had one variable that was being named twice.

## Stop the same eventListener being added more than once

if you define the eventListener function once, it won't be added multiple times. it will just be added once.

```
let link = document.createElement("a");
let imageNameTextNode = document.createTextNode(images[i].name);
let eventListenerFunction = (e) => {
    log('A link was clicked');
  }
document.querySelectorAll('[class^="awsui_tabs-content"]').forEach(linkText => {
  link.addEventListener("click", eventListenerFunction );
});
```

## Add the event listener to the link text:

Then you will have one event listener on each `linkText`. I don't know what a `linkText` is, so I don't know if this is what you want

```
let link = document.createElement("a");
let imageNameTextNode = document.createTextNode(images[i].name);
let eventListenerFunction = 
document.querySelectorAll('[class^="awsui_tabs-content"]').forEach(linkText => {
  linkText.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    log('A link was clicked');
  } );
});
```

Comment: Hi @Sam Spade, thank you for sharing the code. Below resolved my issue. I have learned something new today. Again, thank you very much.                                                                let eventListenerFunction = (e) => {log('A link was clicked'); }
                document.querySelectorAll('[class^="awsui_tabs-content"]').forEach(linkText => {
                link.addEventListener("click", eventListenerFunction );
});

Comment: question if I may, I have 2 test pages, the code works for document.querySelectorAll('[class^="awsui_tabs-content"]') but if I use, document.getElementById('formatted-ticket-content') the codes doesn't work. I would like to know why. Thank you

Comment: @JuanMiguel I'm gonna have to ask you to provide more context. Could you add additional detail and code to your question?

Comment: Hi @Sam Spade, I added the code to my question, please refer to "Using document.getElementById:". The code you shared doesn't work, but if i use this it works, document.getElementById('formatted-ticket-content').addEventListener("click", () => log('A link was clicker'));

Comment: @JuanMiguel I'll be honest, you have a lot of elements floating around. Elements you just created, elements from the DOM, some other elements you don't seem to reference. I have no idea what any of them are, which ones are links (they seem to all be names some variation of link), which ones you want handlers on. If you want more help that this, I'm gonna need more clarification. Perhaps a fiddle or a minimum reproducable example?

Comment: I will try to figure it out but thank you for providing the solution. Will send you the example if necessary. Again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the listener multiple times to the same element.

Assuming the elements you click have the class "awsui_tabs-content":

```html
<div class="awsui_tabs-content">...</div>
```

Try something like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[class^="awsui_tabs-content"]').forEach(linkElement => {
  linkElement.addEventListener("click", (clickEvent) => {
    log('A link was clicked: ' + linkElement.className);
  });
});
```